# Login php script unable to call infromation from db

Tags: php

Good day.
So below i have a `php` script that is supposed to query my db and look for user details. the db is set up and the data is available in it. the issue here seems that once i click the submit button with my user entered details, it fails on the first if statement, to see if the email exists. i am not sure why.
But here is the submit form.

```
<form  action = "submit2.php"  method="Post" >
<div class="row form-group">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <!-- <label for="email">Email</label> -->
        <input type="text" id="email"  name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Your user name">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row form-group">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <!-- <label for="subject">Subject</label> -->
        <input type="text" id="password"  name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Password">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="submit" value="Login" class="btn btn-primary">
</div></form>
```

and here is the submit2.php that is supposed to manipulate the data from the form and query the db.

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once('connect.php');

if(isset($_POST) & !empty($_POST)){

$useremail = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['email']);
$userpassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['password']);


if (empty($useremail) || empty($userpassword)){
    header("Location: customerportal.php?login=empty");
    exit();
}
else{       
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM 'USERS' where EMAIL ='$useremail';";
            $emailresult = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
            $emailresultcheck = mysqli_num_rows($emailresult);
            //check if email exists
            if($emailresultcheck == 0){
                header("Location: customerportal.php?login=invalidEmail");
            }
            else {                  
                if($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($emailresult)){

                    //dehash the password
                    $hashedPWDCheck = password_verify($userpassword,$row['ENCRYPTEDPWD']);
                    if($hashedPWDCheck == false){
                        header("Location: customerportal.php?login=passwordincorrect");
                        exit();
                    }
                    elseif($hashedPWDCheck == true){
                        $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
                        // header("Location: Landingpage.php"); 
                        echo "Success";
                    }
            }

            else{
                header("Location: customerportal.php?login=invalid");   
                exit(); 
                }
            }               
}   
}   
?>
```

The submit always fails else statement and returns the invalidEmail header location and i am not sure why. the Connection file is below.what am i missing?

```
<?php
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "");
if(!$connection){
    echo "Failed to connect database" . die(mysqli_error($connection));;
}
$dbselect = mysqli_select_db($connection, "dhctest");
if(!$dbselect){
    echo "Failed to Select database" . die(mysqli_error($connection));
}
?>
```

Comment: do a var_dump($emailresultcheck) and share the output

Comment: I ran a var_dump and got the following output   C:\wamp64\www\dhc-sa\Submit2.php:16:null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so  solved the issue, by running a var_dump() on everyone of my variables until i came across the error that was being outputted by my sql code.
On the line

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM 'USERS' where EMAIL = '$useremail';";
```

I had to remove the '' and replace with ``.
And that seems to have solved the issue.

Thank you for everyone who assisted.

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM 'USERS' where EMAIL = '$useremail';";
```

to this

```
$sql = "select * from users where email = $useremail";
```

Comment: and try to make variable names camelcase like this $userEmail